# How do i enable a third party payment gateway (not supported today by Shopify)

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopify

In india, Shopify supports the following payment gateways:

1. Citrus Payment
2. Direc Pay
3. PayU India
4. PayU Paisa

But we have an existing merchant account with Axis Bank.
I have no idea where to configure my Axis Bank Payment Gateway with Shopify.

So the question is:

**How do i configure my Axis Bank Payment Gateway with Shopify?**

**Is it even possible to add other payment gateways, which asre not yet supported (not listed in their store admin panel) by Shopify?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a connector for that Gateway that follows the ActiveMerchant pattern. Once it is all tested and works, submit it to Shopify for approval. At that point it becomes an available choice inside Shopify. The ActiveMerchant project spells out all the details for you.

Comment: hi, i have been looking around the Shopify's ActiveMerchant hosted in github, and i saw there is branch for MIGS ( Mastercard Internet Gateway Service ), fortunately Axis bank also powered by MIGS only.

I examine the MIGS branch code, and i am sure that is compatible with Axis bank.

But i am not seeing MIGS payment gateway at Shopify's store Admin -> Settings -> Checkout -> Accept Credit Cards. do i have to make any request to Shopify in order to enable it.

please guide me.

Comment: @mycholan Yes. Once the payment gateway is added and approved by ActiveMerchant maintainers, then you need to speak to Shopify so they can add it to their system.

Comment: What to do if Shopify rejects to support the payment gateway? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311823/how-do-i-enable-a-third-party-payment-gateway-which-shopify-does-not-want-to-sup?lq=1

Comment: Cry? Kick and scream and roll on floor asking for chocolate? Bribery?